# Two Columns with different Query select at a time

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables `"Staffs"` and `"Staffjoins"`,

In `Staffs`:
two columns:

```
"sid"- teacher ID (primary Key) 
"Sname"- Name of Teacher
```

In `Staffjoins`:
three columns

```
"sid"-teacher ID foreign key (refrences from Staffs table)
"cname" - college name,
"Salary" - teacher salary
```

My Question is:

I am entering 10 rows in staffs with unique `sid` and also enter `sname` with `sid`.

Then I enter 10 rows in staffjoins table where I entered:
3 rows with  `cname="College1"`,
2 rows with `cname="College2"`,
2 rows with `cname="College3"`,
3 rows with `cname="College4"`.

In all rows have "`salary`" and different `sid` also then I want to take the name of teacher who earn the highest salary of each College with college name.

Comment: where is the actual question here?

Comment: What did you try before posting the question? Or is it "Do my homework"?

Answer (score 1):

Salary is in the wrong table,  and there should be a colleges table.

Best you can do is something like this.

```
Select c.cname, t.Sname
From StaffJoins c
Inner join (Select cname, Max(Salary) as Salary From StaffJoins) as biggestearners
on biggestearners.cname = c.name and biggestearners.salary = c.salary
inner join Staff t on c.sid = t.sid
```